# While (isspace(array))

Tags: c, arrays, ctype

How can I make the "while" function stop when the i position is a blank space?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main ()
{

    int i,t;
    char array[20];

    t=strlen(array);

    for (i=0;i<=t;i++)
    {
        if(isspace(expressio[i])){
            while (expressio[i+1]!=isspace(expressio[i+1]))
                i=i+1;
            if (isspace(expressio[i+1]))
                { code follows here...}
```

Can I do it like this?

I am programming in C.

Comment: What do you mean by _stop_? If you want to break the loop, use `break;`

Comment: while (!isspace(expressio[i+1])) ?

Comment: note that `break` will only break you out of the _current_ loop. So if you call `break` in the `while` loop above, you'll still be in the `for` loop. If you want to break out of all the loops, you can 1) use `goto` to jump to a label outside of all the loops 2) make `i>t`, so that the condition for the `for` loop now fails, or 3) `return` if you're done with the function at that point.

Comment: I mean, I don't know how to say to the program: When you find a position in the array that is a blank space, tell me how many positions there are between the 2 blank spaces(for example)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this.

```
while (expressio[i+1]!=isspace(expressio[i+1]))
```

makes no sense.  `expressio[i+1]` is a character, while `isspace(expressio[i+1])` is either 1 or 0.  You compare apples to oranges.

Besides,

```
char array[20];

t=strlen(array);
```

makes no sense, either.  If you write a string to the `array`, then `strlen`  would return the length of that string.  Calling `strlen` before initializing `array` is useless (and it may return just anything).